# RegressionGLM/poisson test takes forever to finish generating model and how to read h2o logs

Tags: h2o, poisson

I would like to know what the entries in the h2o logs mean. The logs came from a test (glm, poisson, y=testcolA) that ran for hours long (>= 6 hours and counting) that we had to stop it. A similar test (glm, poisson, y=testcolB) finished within an hour or so. Trainingset size is 131GB.

Cluster info:

```
R is connected to the H2O cluster:
   H2O cluster uptime:         17 seconds 996 milliseconds
   H2O cluster timezone:       Etc/UTC
   H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC
   H2O cluster version:        3.24.0.3
   H2O cluster version age:    5 months and 18 days !!!
   H2O cluster name:           h2o-ca60e2ab-9e9b-4154-bb35-a52fc092abdd
   H2O cluster total nodes:    12
   H2O cluster total memory:   372.00 GB
   H2O cluster total cores:    96
   H2O cluster allowed cores:  96
   H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE
   H2O Connection ip:          localhost
   H2O Connection port:        3000
   H2O Connection proxy:       NA
   H2O Internal Security:      FALSE
   H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4
   R Version:                  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
```

Log snippet:

```
...snip...
10-25 22:05:30.111 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: Building H2O GLM model with these parameters:
10-25 22:05:30.122 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: {"_train":{"name":"RTMP_sid_9e49_4","type":"Key"},"_valid":null,"_nfolds":0,"_keep_cross_validation_models":true,"_keep_cross_validation_predictions":false,"_keep_cross_validation_fold_assignment":false,"_parallelize_cross_validation":true,"_auto_rebalance":true,"_seed":-1,"_fold_assignment":"AUTO","_categorical_encoding":"AUTO","_max_categorical_levels":10,"_distribution":"AUTO","_tweedie_power":1.5,"_quantile_alpha":0.5,"_huber_alpha":0.9,"_ignored_columns":[...snip...],"_ignore_const_cols":true,"_weights_column":null,"_offset_column":null,"_fold_column":null,"_check_constant_response":true,"_is_cv_model":false,"_score_each_iteration":false,"_max_runtime_secs":0.0,"_stopping_rounds":3,"_stopping_metric":"deviance","_stopping_tolerance":1.0E-4,"_response_column":snip,"_balance_classes":false,"_max_after_balance_size":5.0,"_class_sampling_factors":null,"_max_confusion_matrix_size":20,"_checkpoint":null,"_pretrained_autoencoder":null,"_custom_metric_func":null,"_export_checkpoints_dir":null,"_standardize":true,"_family":"poisson","_link":"family_default","_solver":"AUTO","_tweedie_variance_power":0.0,"_tweedie_link_power":1.0,"_theta":1.0E-10,"_invTheta":1.0E10,"_alpha":null,"_lambda":null,"_missing_values_handling":"MeanImputation","_prior":-1.0,"_lambda_search":false,"_nlambdas":-1,"_non_negative":false,"_exactLambdas":false,"_lambda_min_ratio":-1.0,"_use_all_factor_levels":false,"_max_iterations":-1,"_intercept":true,"_beta_epsilon":1.0E-4,"_objective_epsilon":-1.0,"_gradient_epsilon":-1.0,"_obj_reg":-1.0,"_compute_p_values":false,"_remove_collinear_columns":false,"_interactions":null,"_interaction_pairs":null,"_early_stopping":true,"_beta_constraints":null,"_max_active_predictors":-1,"_stdOverride":false}
10-25 22:05:30.127 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: Dropping ignored columns: [..snip..]
10-25 22:05:30.132 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: train dataset already contains 489 (non-empty)  chunks. No need to rebalance. [desiredChunks=8, rebalanceRatio=1.0]
10-25 22:05:35.360 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: Starting model MyModel
10-25 22:05:35.557 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=0 lmb=.14E2 obj=530570.0 imp=.1E1 bdf=.11E2] Got 2151 active columns out of 2163 total
10-25 22:05:35.558 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=0 lmb=.14E2 obj=530570.0 imp=.1E1 bdf=.11E2] picked solver IRLSM
10-25 23:20:14.377 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-25 23:20:14.377 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 0.27587151573955293 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-25 23:20:14.378 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=0 lmb=.14E2 obj=530570.0 imp=.1E1 bdf=.11E2] computed in 4383038+95782=4478820ms, step = 1, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 0.27587151573955293
10-26 00:31:02.569 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=1 lmb=.14E2 obj=525370.0 imp=.98E-2 bdf=.94E0] Scoring after 8732476ms
10-26 00:31:20.993 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=1 lmb=.14E2 obj=525370.0 imp=.98E-2 bdf=.94E0] Training metrics computed in 18424ms
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=1 lmb=.14E2 obj=525370.0 imp=.98E-2 bdf=.94E0] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 3.63462328E11
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 602878.4
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 525228.0
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 130539.59
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.968928
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042488E7
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.275379E12
10-26 00:31:20.994 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2753832E12
10-26 00:31:21.088 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=1 lmb=.14E2 obj=525370.0 imp=.98E-2 bdf=.94E0] computed in 4182012+1+84696=4266709ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 0.27587151573955293
10-26 01:37:31.864 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 01:37:31.864 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 55571.13056411838 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 01:38:38.508 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=2 lmb=.14E2 obj=524670.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.65E0] Scoring after 4037421ms
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=2 lmb=.14E2 obj=524670.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.65E0] Training metrics computed in 17184ms
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=2 lmb=.14E2 obj=524670.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.65E0] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 3.48753723E11
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 590553.75
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 524416.7
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 130637.945
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.955455
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042486E7
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.26723E12
10-26 01:38:55.693 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2672342E12
10-26 01:38:55.704 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=2 lmb=.14E2 obj=524670.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.65E0] computed in 3914318+56458+83839=4054615ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 55571.13056411838
10-26 02:44:41.208 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 02:44:41.208 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 5768.096703827045 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 02:46:20.563 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=3 lmb=.14E2 obj=523790.0 imp=.17E-2 bdf=.11E0] Scoring after 4044860ms
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=3 lmb=.14E2 obj=523790.0 imp=.17E-2 bdf=.11E0] Training metrics computed in 19030ms
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=3 lmb=.14E2 obj=523790.0 imp=.17E-2 bdf=.11E0] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 3.48649226E11
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 590465.25
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 523514.56
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 130344.89
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.952192
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042381E7
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2581693E12
10-26 02:46:39.594 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2581735E12
10-26 02:46:39.601 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=3 lmb=.14E2 obj=523790.0 imp=.17E-2 bdf=.11E0] computed in 3889387+56117+118392=4063896ms, step = 0.10890000000000001, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 5768.096703827045
10-26 03:52:19.527 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 03:52:19.527 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 4784.969933090491 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 03:53:25.773 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=4 lmb=.14E2 obj=523120.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.46E0] Scoring after 4006173ms
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=4 lmb=.14E2 obj=523120.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.46E0] Training metrics computed in 20423ms
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=4 lmb=.14E2 obj=523120.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.46E0] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 4.97980703E11
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 705677.5
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 522778.22
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 130602.62
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.941541
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042353E7
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2507737E12
10-26 03:53:46.196 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2507779E12
10-26 03:53:46.201 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=4 lmb=.14E2 obj=523120.0 imp=.13E-2 bdf=.46E0] computed in 3886191+53735+86674=4026600ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 4784.969933090491
10-26 04:59:31.210 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 04:59:31.211 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 44821.17005179174 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 05:01:09.199 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=5 lmb=.14E2 obj=522540.0 imp=.11E-2 bdf=.98E-1] Scoring after 4042998ms
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=5 lmb=.14E2 obj=522540.0 imp=.11E-2 bdf=.98E-1] Training metrics computed in 20907ms
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=5 lmb=.14E2 obj=522540.0 imp=.11E-2 bdf=.98E-1] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 4.94325006E11
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 703082.5
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 522180.72
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 130517.93
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.93738
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.004234E7
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2447722E12
10-26 05:01:30.107 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2447763E12
10-26 05:01:30.118 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=5 lmb=.14E2 obj=522540.0 imp=.11E-2 bdf=.98E-1] computed in 3888934+56076+118907=4063917ms, step = 0.10890000000000001, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 44821.17005179174
10-26 06:07:41.261 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 06:07:41.261 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 56532.11099690192 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 06:08:47.588 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=6 lmb=.14E2 obj=521080.0 imp=.28E-2 bdf=.28E0] Scoring after 4037470ms
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=6 lmb=.14E2 obj=521080.0 imp=.28E-2 bdf=.28E0] Training metrics computed in 21232ms
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=6 lmb=.14E2 obj=521080.0 imp=.28E-2 bdf=.28E0] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 5.12239665E11
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 715709.2
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 520660.66
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 130576.516
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.925282
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042325E7
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2295049E12
10-26 06:09:08.822 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2295091E12
10-26 06:09:08.827 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=6 lmb=.14E2 obj=521080.0 imp=.28E-2 bdf=.28E0] computed in 3911274+59869+87566=4058709ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 56532.11099690192
10-26 07:15:06.827 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 07:15:06.827 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 60485.20087029953 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 07:16:10.428 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=7 lmb=.14E2 obj=520960.0 imp=.22E-3 bdf=.19E0] Scoring after 4021601ms
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=7 lmb=.14E2 obj=520960.0 imp=.22E-3 bdf=.19E0] Training metrics computed in 22090ms
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=7 lmb=.14E2 obj=520960.0 imp=.22E-3 bdf=.19E0] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 5.692472E11
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 754484.75
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 520506.1
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 131249.19
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.91393
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.004232E7
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2279525E12
10-26 07:16:32.518 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2279567E12
10-26 07:16:32.523 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=7 lmb=.14E2 obj=520960.0 imp=.22E-3 bdf=.19E0] computed in 3892837+65163+85696=4043696ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 60485.20087029953
10-26 08:22:34.254 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 08:22:34.254 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 87496.09341881957 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 08:24:11.293 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=8 lmb=.14E2 obj=520840.0 imp=.24E-3 bdf=.42E-1] Scoring after 4058770ms
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=8 lmb=.14E2 obj=520840.0 imp=.24E-3 bdf=.42E-1] Training metrics computed in 21569ms
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=8 lmb=.14E2 obj=520840.0 imp=.24E-3 bdf=.42E-1] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 5.503653E11
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 741866.06
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 520372.72
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 131350.28
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.910981
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042317E7
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2266129E12
10-26 08:24:32.863 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2266171E12
10-26 08:24:32.868 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=8 lmb=.14E2 obj=520840.0 imp=.24E-3 bdf=.42E-1] computed in 3904152+57579+118614=4080345ms, step = 0.10890000000000001, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 87496.09341881957
10-26 09:30:37.337 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 09:30:37.337 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 46878.36427637116 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 09:31:42.658 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=9 lmb=.14E2 obj=519810.0 imp=.2E-2 bdf=.11E0] Scoring after 4029790ms
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=9 lmb=.14E2 obj=519810.0 imp=.2E-2 bdf=.11E0] Training metrics computed in 21189ms
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=9 lmb=.14E2 obj=519810.0 imp=.2E-2 bdf=.11E0] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 4.78805721E11
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 691957.9
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 519314.25
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 131280.0
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.902149
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042314E7
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2159814E12
10-26 09:32:03.847 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2159856E12
10-26 09:32:03.853 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=9 lmb=.14E2 obj=519810.0 imp=.2E-2 bdf=.11E0] computed in 3909384+55085+86516=4050985ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 46878.36427637116
10-26 10:38:06.545 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 10:38:06.545 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 153149.48474907267 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 10:39:13.512 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=10 lmb=.14E2 obj=519560.0 imp=.48E-3 bdf=.75E-1] Scoring after 4029658ms
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=10 lmb=.14E2 obj=519560.0 imp=.48E-3 bdf=.75E-1] Training metrics computed in 21204ms
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=10 lmb=.14E2 obj=519560.0 imp=.48E-3 bdf=.75E-1] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 5.12623084E11
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 715977.0
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 519042.94
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 131338.34
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.894209
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042305E7
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2132567E12
10-26 10:39:34.716 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2132609E12
10-26 10:39:34.720 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=10 lmb=.14E2 obj=519560.0 imp=.48E-3 bdf=.75E-1] computed in 3906292+56400+88175=4050867ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 153149.48474907267
10-26 11:45:29.369 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver stopped after 10000 iterations. (max_iter=10000)
10-26 11:45:29.369 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   WARN: ADMM solver finished with gerr = 44089.34572744647 >  eps = 1.0E-4
10-26 11:46:35.949 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=11 lmb=.14E2 obj=519210.0 imp=.66E-3 bdf=.83E-1] Scoring after 4021229ms
10-26 11:46:58.380 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=11 lmb=.14E2 obj=519210.0 imp=.66E-3 bdf=.83E-1] Training metrics computed in 22431ms
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=11 lmb=.14E2 obj=519210.0 imp=.66E-3 bdf=.83E-1] Model Metrics Type: RegressionGLM
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  Description: N/A
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  model id: MyModel
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  frame id: RTMP_sid_9e49_4
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  MSE: 4.48644973E11
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  RMSE: 669809.6
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean residual deviance: 518686.6
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  mean absolute error: 131270.0
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  root mean squared log error: 10.888633
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null DOF: 1.0043978E7
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual DOF: 1.0042303E7
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  null deviance: 5.3290043E12
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  residual deviance: 5.2096774E12
10-26 11:46:58.381 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO:  AIC: 5.2096816E12
10-26 11:46:58.385 172.31.20.64:3000     206    FJ-1-23   INFO: GLM[dest=MyModel, iter=11 lmb=.14E2 obj=519210.0 imp=.66E-3 bdf=.83E-1] computed in 3896878+57770+89016=4043664ms, step = 0.33, l1solver iter = 10000, gerr = 44089.34572744647
10-26 11:54:31.824 172.31.20.64:3000     206    #191:3000 ERRR: Got IO error when sending batch UDP bytes: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
10-26 11:54:31.829 172.31.20.64:3000     206    #106:3000 ERRR: Got IO error when sending batch UDP bytes: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated that your data is around `131GB`, which is quite large, so the model training and testing will take significant amount of time.

Below are the official docs for training the `GLM-poisson` model in `h2o`, this also includes all the parameters present during training, and also explains how to interpret the model output parameters.

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html

https://www.h2o.ai/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/GLM-BOOKLET.pdf